# Finding the Complexity of Nested Loops (Big O)

Tags: big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory, pseudocode, discrete-mathematics

I'm given the following nested loops, and I'm told to find it's complexity.

Where "to" is "<=" 
In pseudocode:

```
sum = 0;
for i=1 to n
  for j = 1 to i^2
    if(j (mod i) = 0) then
      for k = 1 to j
        sum++
```

I know that the outermost loop runs n times, the next loop should run n^2 times, but I have no idea how to calculate the next.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We can analyze your algorithm using Sigma notation. We note that

```
j (mod i) = 0 <=> j is a multiple of i
```

We calculate the number of times we execute the `sum++` statement, leaving out counting the iterations where the inner loop is not reached; acceptable as this case will be of lower order (`~n^3`) than the growth of total iterations w.r.t. the executing the `sum++` command of the inner loop.

Sigma notation analysis:

[image: Sigma]

Where summation rule [`(+)` is from Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20j%5E3,%20j%3D1%20to%20n).

Consequently, `O(n^4)` describes an upper bound on the asymptotic behaviour of your algorithm.